# DreamFactory - Guest user setup to access only the Database service

Tags: rest

I am using the builtin Local DB (MySql) in DreamFactory and I am trying to access a GET on https://my_dsp/rest/db/my_table from Postman as a guest(without any kind of authentication). I am getting

```
"context": null,
"message": "No application name header or parameter value in request.",
"code": 400
```

Here is what i did as per the instruction
1. Setup Schema and added data to the existing Database service which comes with the dsp 
2. Set up a role name and desc
3. gave a GET service access(Database) to the role with Component * for all. Nothing is done in User tab or lookup key
4. Ticked on Config - > allow guest user and selected the role

Its working fine from API Docs (/db/{table_name}) but cant access it from Postman or other place. All the settings are updated and I flush the system cache as well. What am I exactly missing? Some help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is unrelated to your guest access configuration or your DB configuration. You have failed to provide an application name header or URI parameter in your API call. I recommend you review [the product documentation on the basics of making a call to DreamFactory](https://github.com/dreamfactorysoftware/dsp-core/wiki/Common-Headers-Parameters#api-key-currently-also-referred-to-as-application-name).

In short, in Postman, you will need to either provide your application name in a URI parameter, like

```
https://my_dsp/rest/db/my_table?app_name={myappname}
```

Or as an HTTP header, like

```
X-DreamFactory-Application-Name: {myappname}
```

I recently answered this with [a step-by-step guide on the DreamFactory forum here](http://community.dreamfactory.com/t/guest-users-authentication/1121/3?u=jeffreystables).